# If $X = \{ |p(z)|<c\}$, show that the boundary of $X$ is $\{ |p(z)| = c\}$ and each component of $X$ contains a zero of $p$.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I am trying problems in complex analysis of an institute in which I don't study and I got struck on this particular problem.

> Let $p$ be a non-constant polynomial, $c>0$ and $X=\{z:p(z)<c\}$. Prove that $\partial X=\{z:|p(z)|=c\}$ and also each connected component of $X$ contains a zero $p$.

Attempt : Let $C$ be connected component of $X$ . Then $\partial C$ is a  subset of $\partial X$ and so $|p(z)| \leq c$. But I cant think any other argument other than this.

So, kindly shed some light on how this problem should be approached.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yes p is complex and and there is no information regaring zeroes in question .

Comment: Do you know the minimum modulus principle?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes i have studied it!!

Comment: Then the second part follows immediately from the first. So it remains to show $\partial X = \{ z : \lvert p(z)\rvert = c\}$. For that, it's useful to be aware that $X$ is open.

Comment: @DanielFischer I dont get how 2nd will follow immediately from 1st . Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Since $p$ isn't constant, $X$ is bounded. Next, if $z_0 \in C$ you have $\lvert p(z_0)\rvert < \min \{ \lvert p(z)\rvert : z \in \partial C\}$ by the first part. The minimum modulus principle tells you $p$ has a zero in $C$.

Comment: @DanielFischer It would really help me if you can post a detailed answer for both the parts if you have some spare time . I am  really struck on it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple properties of $p$:

i) Since $p$ is a nonconstant polynomial, $p$ takes on every complex value. Thus the sets $X=\{|p|<c\}$ and $\{|p|=c\}$ are nonempty.

ii) The set $X$ is open by the continuity of $|p|.$

iii) $|p(z)|\to \infty$ as $|z|\to\infty.$

From iii) it follows that $X$ is bounded. Otherwise $X$ would contain a sequence $z_n$ such that $|z_n|\to \infty,$ hence $|p(z_n)|\to \infty,$ violating the definition of $X.$

Let $z\in \partial X.$ Then $z$ is the limit of a sequence in $X.$ This implies $|p(z)|\le c.$ Could $|p(z)|<c$ happen? No, because then $z\in X$ and it couldn't be a boundary point. It follows that $\partial X\subset \{|p|=c\}.$

Now suppose $|p(z)|=c.$ Let $r>0.$ Then $p(D(z,r))$ is open by the open mapping theorem, hence contains points of modulus less than $c$ and points of modulus greater than $c.$ Thus $D(z,r)\cap X$ and $D(z,r)\cap X^c$ are both nonempty. Since $r$ was arbitrary, $z\in \partial X.$ This with the last paragraph proves $\partial X = \{|p|=c\}.$

Recall the maximum modulus theorem: Suppose $U$ is a bounded open connected set. Let $f$ be continuous on $\overline U$ and holomorphic on $U.$ If the maximum of $|f|$ occurs in $U,$ then $f$ is constant.

So now let $C$ be a connected component of $X.$ We know $\partial C \subset \partial X,$ which implies $|p|=c$ on $\partial C.$ And of course $|p|<c$ in $C.$

Assume $C$ does not contain a zero of $p.$ Then $p$ is nonzero on $\overline C,$ a compact set. Thus $|p|$ attains a positive minimum at some in $z_0 \in \overline C.$ By the MMT, $z_0\in C.$ But notice $1/p$ satisfies the hypotheses of the MMT. Thus, using MMT again,

$$\frac{1}{|p(z_0)|} < \max_{\partial C}\frac{1}{|p|} =\frac{1}{c}.$$

Since $|p(z_0|<c,$ we have a contradiction, and we're done.

Comment: Can you please tell how to prove or give a reference to (i) of answer that every polynomial (non- constant) takes every value(to be used in proving the set X={|p|=c} is non-empty)?

Comment: Suppose $p$ is a polynomial of degree at least $1$ and $w\in \mathbb C.$ Then $p(z)-w$ is a polynomial of degree at least $1.$ By the fundamental theorem of algebra, $ p(z)-w = 0$ for some $z\in \mathbb C.$ Thus $p(z)=w$ for some $z.$ It follows that every polynomial of degree at least $1$ takes on every complex value.

Comment: I think in last 6th line it should be p instead of |f|<c

Comment: @Ben Right, in the paragraph starting "So now ...", thanks, edited.